# In Javascript, does "this.something" look up the scope chain for "something"?

Tags: javascript, oop, scope, javascript-objects

Here's what I mean. I'm practicing my object-oriented Javascript (I learn by practice), created the following class for fun

```
function Funcstack ( ) 
{
      this.stack = []; // stack/array of functions w/ no params

      this.pushFunction = function ( f ) 
      {
         // f: function w/ no params
         this.stack.push(f);
      }

      this.popFunction = function ( f )
      {
        // f: function w/ no params   
          var n = this.stack.length;
          if (n > 0) this.stack.splice(n - 1, 1);
      }
      this.executeFunctions = function ( ) 
      {
          // execute functions from top to bottom of stack
          for ( var i = (this.stack.length - 1); i >= 0; --i )
          {
             var thisfunc = this.stack[i];    
             thisfunc();
          }
      }
}

var fs = new Funcstack();
fs.pushFunction(function() { console.log('z'); });
fs.pushFunction(function() { console.log('y'); });
fs.pushFunction(function() { console.log('x'); });
fs.executeFunctions(); // should print 'xyz'
```

and was surprised that it worked. The main reason is because I thought that, for example, in

```
      this.pushFunction = function ( f ) 
      {
         // f: function w/ no params
         this.stack.push(f);
      }
```

the body of the function wouldn't recognize `this.stack` because `this` in the particular context refers to the invoking function `pushFunction` which doesn't have a member named `stack`! So am I correct in thinking that it looked up the scope chain? That seems to contradict the whole idea of `this`, though ... What's the point of it?

Comment: Your calling context is "fs" which is an instance of "Funstack" class and that class has a member called "stack"...

Comment: when in doubt ...`console.log(this)` or walk through breakpoints

Comment: @charlietfl The correct motto is "When in doubt, ask S.O."

Comment: well there is the old adage .... *give a man a fish....or teach him to fish*

Comment: Unrelated: you can use `this.popFunction = function(){ this.stack.pop(); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is "No". An execution context's *this* is always resolved in the current execution context, therefore it has nothing to do with scope. With broad arrow functions, it's set to the same value as the outer execution context.

A function's *this* is set by how the function is called or by setting with *bind*. It's not set lexically (where the call is in the code) or where the function is called from.

Where *this* is an object (always in non–strict mode) then its properties are resolved in the same way any object's properties are resolved, firstly on itself, then on its `[[Prototype]]` chain. Where a function is called as a method of an object:

```
fs.executeFunctions();
```

then the *base object* (fs) is set to *this* within the function. Therefore, when *this.stack.length* is resolved, *this* references the *fs* instance and *executeFunctions* is resolved as a property of *fs*.

Comment: *With broad arrow functions ...* What does this mean?

Comment: @JaredFarrish—ECMAScript 2015 introduces [*arrow functions*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-arrow-function-definitions) to create concise function expressions, e.g. the function expression `function(a){return a*3}` may be replaced by `a => a*3`. Also see [*MDN Arrow functions*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: @JaredFarrish—indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it works is because of the calling context.

> this.stack = []; // <--- is an instance property ( member ) of any instance of Funstack

When you invoke "pushFunction" using "fs" ( the instance reference ) to reference

"this" ( the context ) becomes whatever "fs" object is..

If it still unclear, try reading more on javascript's "calling context".

Comment: *this* is not "context", it is a parameter of an execution context that is set by the call, or *bind* (or in ECMAScript 2015 arrow functions, to the other execution context's *this*).

Answer (score 0):

When you say: `var fs = new Funcstack();`, you're declaring an object that is an instance of the class `Funcstack`. Note that inside the `constructor`, you are declaring some properties and methods of it.

So, the keyword `this` in all those methods will refer to the object you've created. You can change the context by using [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) if you want, at anytime.

Note that you are declaring the `pushFunction` as a member of the class by saying: `this.pushFunction = function(f) { /* (...) */ }`. So, you're creating a method into the class. That's why the `this` keyword refers to the object that is an instance of that class.

If you declared the function as `var pushf = function(f) { /* (...) */ }`, and then called that function inside some method of the class `Funcstack`, you would get the error:

> TypeError: this.stack is undefined

Take a look at the example below.

```js
function Funcstack() {
  this.stack = []; // stack/array of functions w/ no params

  var pushf = function _pushFunction(f) {
    this.stack.push(f);
  }

  this.pushFunction = function(f) {
    // f: function w/ no params
    pushf(f);
  }

  this.popFunction = function(f) {
    // f: function w/ no params   
    var n = this.stack.length;
    if (n > 0) this.stack.splice(n - 1, 1);
  }
  this.executeFunctions = function() {
    // execute functions from top to bottom of stack
    for (var i = (this.stack.length - 1); i >= 0; --i) {
      var thisfunc = this.stack[i];
      thisfunc();
    }
  }
}

var fs = new Funcstack();
fs.pushFunction(function() {
  console.log('z');
});
fs.pushFunction(function() {
  console.log('y');
});
fs.pushFunction(function() {
  console.log('x');
});
fs.executeFunctions(); // should print 'xyz'
```

Comment: *"You can change the context by using `call`, `apply` or `bind` if you want, at anytime."* - Note that those aren't the only ways to change what `this` will be inside those functions.

Comment: Besides those ways, and by using vnext fat arrows, what are the other ways? (Not joking here, I really would like to know)

Comment: @Buzinas—strict mode, *new*, calling a function as a method of some other object (i.e. a different base object) as in `b.foo = a.foo; b.foo()`. While the term "context" is often used for *this*, it is a malapropism. When a function is called as a method, the object that will be set as the *this* value of its execution context is called the *base reference* by the specification, so it will would seem reasonable to call it the *base object* to distinguish how *this* is set in that case.

Comment: See *GetBase* within [*The Reference Specification Type*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-reference-specification-type) (damn these long URLs…).

Comment: The examples RobG gave are the sort of thing I was thinking of. `x = a.foo; x();` - functions that are "methods" don't really belong to a particular object, that object just has a reference to them.